# Getting info for undocumented APIs called by StartServiceCtrlDispatcher

Tags: windows, windbg, callstack

I'm trying to understand the inner workings of [`StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, I'm trying to figure out how it determines if its being called from the SCM. So I write a simple service in C# and called it as a console app. I started it from WinDbg and set a breakpoint at `ADVAPI32!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherWStub`. I then stepped into a few calls until I got the following stack trace:

```
0:000> kP
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0037e578 00007ffa`101a52be RPCRT4!RpcStringBindingComposeW+0xff
00000000`0037e580 00007ffa`101abedf sechost!ScClientBindToServer+0x76
00000000`0037e690 00007ffa`101a8751 sechost!ScOpenServiceChannelHandle+0x1f
00000000`0037e6d0 00007ffa`009796f0 sechost!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0x3c
00000000`0037e710 00007ffa`0097c0af System_ServiceProcess_ni+0x296f0
00000000`0037e7e0 00007ff9`a0730104 System_ServiceProcess_ni+0x2c0af
00000000`0037e880 00007ff9`ffe84113 0x00007ff9`a0730104
00000000`0037e8d0 00007ff9`ffe83fde clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
00000000`0037e910 00007ff9`ffe889a3 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
00000000`0037e950 00007ff9`fff591aa clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
00000000`0037eb00 00007ff9`fff5999a clr!RunMain+0x1e7
00000000`0037ece0 00007ff9`fff59893 clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
00000000`0037efd0 00007ff9`fff59372 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x506
00000000`0037f5e0 00007ff9`fff592c6 clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
00000000`0037f650 00007ff9`fff59d84 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xae
00000000`0037f6e0 00007ffa`011e7ced clr!CorExeMain+0x14
00000000`0037f720 00007ffa`0128ea5b mscoreei!CorExeMain+0xe0
00000000`0037f770 00007ffa`107115cd MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0xcb
00000000`0037f7a0 00007ffa`10a343d1 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`0037f7d0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x2ae4 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000000037e738 00007ffa100795b3 [InlinedCallFrame: 000000000037e738] System.ServiceProcess.NativeMethods.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(IntPtr)
000000000037e738 00007ffa009796f0 [InlinedCallFrame: 000000000037e738] System.ServiceProcess.NativeMethods.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(IntPtr)
000000000037e710 00007ffa009796f0 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr)
000000000037e7e0 00007ffa0097c0af System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[])
000000000037e880 00007ff9a0730104 ConsoleAndSCMPatternDemo.Program.Main(System.String[]) [c:\Users\Justin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleAndSCMPatternDemo\ConsoleAndSCMPatternDemo\Program.cs @ 21]
000000000037ebb0 00007ff9ffe84113 [GCFrame: 000000000037ebb0]
```

I have two questions:

1. What is this `sechost.dll` that seems to have AdvApi32 functionality.
2. Where can I find documentation about the following API calls:

   - `ScClientBindToServer`
   - `ScOpenServiceChannelHandle`

Google doesn't give good info on either.

Comment: `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` is pretty well documented in ReactOS: http://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/da0/sctrl_8c_a1c10607bf2a903bd52faf7e1cf7dd53f.html

Comment: The file description for sechost.dll says "Host for SCM/SDDL/LSA Lookup APIs" which seems pretty self explanatory to me. Was there something about that description you didn't understand? FWIW, I thought the DLL names in sechost.dll, API-MS-Win-Core*.dll, were curious, as I've never seen DLLs with those names as part of a Windows install.